# wp e-commerce discounts - If product is in category

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I have been customising the WP Ecommence plugin to enable a discount for every two items of a certain category. I know that the categories are listed in the `$wpsc_cart` array but this is not working and I cannot see why. Ideally I would like to scrap this in favor of something simpler, and that is for question part 2 below.

My code-

```
foreach($wpsc_cart->cart_items->wpsc_cart_item as $cartItemDW){
        $ii = 1;
        if(in_array('product-type-1',$cartItemDW->category_list) || in_array('product-type-2',$cartItemDW->category_list)){
            $ii++;  
        }
    }
    //Pull up end count
    $prodCount = $ii;
    //Round off to even number
    if($prodCount % 2){
        $prodCount = $prodCount - 1;    
    }
    // Discount for every second one
    $prodCount = $prodCount / 2;
    // Discount of £70 per second item
    $prodCount = $prodCount * 70.00;
    // Pass discount to Paypal Array
    if($discount > 0){
        $paypal_vars += array(
            'discount_amount' => $discount
        );
    }
```

**PART 2**
Ideally I would like to find out how to get the category name(s) based upon the item ID in the table `_wpsc_cart_contents` and then say if it is in certain categories, discount accordingly, seemingly a much easier approach than the foreach that is likely totally off. Can someone please explain how to get the product category based on the product ID?

thanks in advance. Dan

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer 1- in the foreach item -

```
$prodID = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM wp_wpsc_item_category_assoc WHERE product_id = "'.$item['prodid'].'"');
            if($prodID->category_id == 10 || $prodID->category_id == 5 || $prodID->category_id == 23 || $prodID->category_id == 24 || $prodID->category_id == 25 || $prodID->category_id == 26){
                $addQuantity = $item['quantity'];
                $i = $i + $addQuantity;
                //$i++;

            }
```

and then later, 2- after the foreach item-

```
$prodCount = $i;
$discount = 70.00 * ($prodCount / 2);

$data['discount_amount_1'] = number_format(sprintf("%01.2f", $discount),$decimal_places,'.','');
```